# Disable Keychain Permission Dialog?

Tags: objective-c, cocoa, macos, keychain

I wonder if I might disable the keychain dialog that pops up whenever my application wants to access the keychaindata. My app compares a TextField's string with a keychain entry in order to check if the entered Password is correct.

It works fine but it asks for the permission accessing it.

How to avoid this behaviour?

Best regards,
Adrian

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Another advice is to code-sign your executable, even on OS X.

If you don't, then the system always asks the user if s/he allows the program to access the keychain when the program is updated, even when your user selected "Allow Always" before. This is because the system can't tell if the so-called updated program is a genuinely updated version.

As written [in this Apple document](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Security/Conceptual/CodeSigningGuide/AboutCS/AboutCS.html%23//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40005929-CH3-DontLinkElementID_1), if you code-sign, the system doesn't ask the user if s/he allows the program to access the keychain when the program is updated, because the system can tell your new version of the app is really the new version of the app, issued by the same programmer.

So, to minimize the number of keychain dialogues, code-sign your app. Yes it's optional on OS X, unlike on iOS, but it has a few advantages.

Answer (score 8):

This is the intended behaviour, so that Users are in control of what apps can access their keychain. If you want to avoid the prompt click "Allow always" on the dialog.

Comment: "Always Allow" will still only work until the app is updated. The code signing answer is correct.